# Failed build in Jenkins -Maven build failed FATAL: Couldn’t find any executable in null

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3

ERROR: Maven Home null doesn’t exist. Build is successful manually on the master.

Jenkins version :1.624
Maven Version:3.2.3
Please  help me with this error
Tried to set the node level configuration too did not work .
Tried permissions did not work
Maven configurations are all in place, I am not sure why this build is failing through Jenkins.
Is this something I can fix by changing the Jenkins configuration.
ERROR: Maven Home null doesn’t exist
Skipping sonar analysis due to bad build status FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE

Only master is setup.

.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
On the server environment variables, add the maven path under the user ID Jenkins is using to login to the server.

not just under system variables.

That is why build was successful on the machine as maven was specified under system variables and not under "user".

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. I was able to fix it by doing the following:

Manage Jenkins --> Configure System

Scroll down about half way to the Maven section and click Maven installations. Give your path to your Maven install in MAVEN_HOME.

Since we aren't installing Maven through Jenkins (but, rather, manually), I kept skipping this section thinking it didn't pertain to me. But it seems that any Maven projects look here for their Maven path, and that's why it kept turning up as null when I left it blank. I hope this helps!

Here's a screenshot of the section. 
[image: Jenkins Maven configuration]

Comment: My jenkins (version 2.73.2, docker-installation) did not show a field "MAVEN_HOME". MAVEN_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven-Build-In/ - But yes ... checkbox "Install automatically" needs to be disabled. Well, in the first place I checked because I had no maven installed at all, so I checked it in the first run. In the second run I looked up the maven_home within the docker container and then filled in the MAVEN_HOME in the shown gui field.

Answer (score 1):

The new executable is called `mvn.cmd` - however, Jenkins expect the file to be called mvn.bat

So just open a MS-DOS shell and type `copy mvn.cmd mvn.bat` or duplicate the file using Windows Explorer. Then restart Jenkins.

You can also set system wide the environment variables: `M2` and `M2_HOME` - that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a pipeline script making a reference to a NodeJS Plugin Node installation which was duplicated with the same name and different settings, the first one was missing the global package yarn which was required by the pipeline script.